# Path based routing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, http.server

I am trying to write the python code, that return the json output when I `curl localhost:8000`. I want to get the value only when I do `curl localhost:8000/shakespear`. As of the current code I am getting the value at `curl localhost:8000`
main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import json

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        parsed_path = urlparse(self.path)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({
            'myfavourite author name': 'shakespear',
        }).encode())
        return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8000), RequestHandler)
    print('Starting server at http://localhost:8000')
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: See this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346685/11323371). I would suggest using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/]) if possible as it offers a more robust routing.

Comment: I have tried using this but I am unable to route even then, can you tell me where shall I add the if condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an if condition to check if `parsed.path` is the same as your desired endpoint i.e `shakespear`

```py
def do_GET(self):
  ...
  if self.path == '/shakespear':
    self.send_response(200)
    #do stuff
    ...
```

Keep in mind that `/` is part of the `path` string. With `self.path` using `urlparse` is unnecessary

It is meant to be used when you're working with a url that you need parsed.

Example:

As explained in the docs, [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse)
returns a `ParseResult` with the `path` attribute.

Pass the url to `urlparse`:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/shakespear"
parsed = urlparse(url)
```

This returns a `ParseResult` whose `path` attribute you can access:

```py
print(parsed)
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='127.0.0.1:8080', path='/shakespear', 
params='', query='', fragment='')

print(parsed.path)
'/shakespear'
```

Answer (score 0):

you are ignoring the path and sending a general purpose response to each request.
as you can see in RequestHandler class, variable `parsed_path` is ignored and it doesn't matter whats the path, response is a const static thing.
you should change the code and process `parsed_path` and make a appropriate response for each request and put it in `self.wfile.write`

Comment: Hi I am new to python, can you tell me how? Any code snippet would be a great help